# How to encrypt JWT secret code for protect it in case of APK decompilation?

Tags: jwt

I have a problem with JWT. If someone decompiles my APK, they can see the secret code I used to create my token. Example code, the code is secret:

```
    String originalInput = "secret";
    String encodedString =Base64Utils.encode(originalInput.getBytes());
    String jwt = Jwts.builder().claim("emailId","test123@gmail.com").claim("user", "123456")
            .claim("phoneNo", "1111111111")
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, encodedString)
            .compact();
```

Comment: Where do you generate the JWT? And why is the secret hard coded anyway? Depending on what you are trying to do it should be configurable by the user using your application (which is a server?). Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description where you code is used, what you are trying to do and where you want to use JWT (and why). Explain all the different hosts/servers/clients/systems you have and how you plan they interact with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are a client (the APK) and a backend, you should use an asymmetric algorithm such as RS256, PS256 or ES256, not a symmetric one (HS256).

If the issuer of the token is your backend, you only need the public key on client side (your APK). This key can safely be shipped as it is public.

If the client is the issuer, key should not be shipped with your application but generated on the device and securely stored using the Keystore API (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore). The associated public key should be sent to the backend. This means that each client has a uniquely generated private key.

Comment: +1 . Thank you for your answer. This is my problem with how to dynamically generate the same key for everyone to be the same key as the backend.

Comment: You should use an asymmetric algorithm such as RS256, PS256 or ES256, not a symmetric one (HS256). If the issuer of the token is your backend, you only need the public key on client side (your APK). This key can safely be shipped as it is public.